# Did I miss something for Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I installed VSC, Doctor and Android Studio, and I can run emulator without any problems, but I found there is a `!` and two `X` when I run `flutter doctor`, what should I do next?
[image]

Comment: open android studio and install plugins Flutter and Dart.

Comment: I use VSC not use Android Studio, do I have to install plugins for Flutter and Dart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are [safe to ignore these](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/68429#issuecomment-712022319) if using VSC.

Comment: By the way, how can I do if I want to save my free HD?

Answer (score 1):

In VSC go to extension then download and install Flutter and Dart

Comment: No you gonna need Android studio for emulator settings and also to build apk file of your app

Answer (score 1):

Ignore this. Android Studio 4.x has problem plugin compatibility.

Comment: as a matter of fact, removing plugins and re installing them helps.

Answer (score 0):

try to follow this steps

1. Uninstall the android studio flutter and dart plugins from the plugin window of android studio.(double click the shift button and search for plugins).

2.Restart android studio
3 run flutter doctor(and ignore the signs)
4 open android studio and reinstall the plugins

Comment: I use VSC not use Android Studio, do I have to install plugins for Flutter and Dart.